# C++ Polymorphism- find out type of derived class

Tags: c++, casting, polymorphism

I have a hierarchy of classes as follows:

```
class ANIMAL
{
public:
    ANIMAL(...)
        : ...
    {
    }

    virtual ~ANIMAL()
    {}

    bool Reproduce(CELL field[40][30], int x, int y);
};


class HERBIVORE : public ANIMAL
{
public:
    HERBIVORE(...)
        : ANIMAL(...)
    {}
};

class RABBIT : public HERBIVORE
{
public:
    RABBIT()
        : HERBIVORE(10, 45, 3, 25, 10, .50, 40)
    {}
};

class CARNIVORE : public ANIMAL
{
public:
    CARNIVORE(...)
        : ANIMAL(...)
    {}
};

class WOLF : public CARNIVORE
{
public:
    WOLF()
        : CARNIVORE(150, 200, 2, 50, 45, .40, 190, 40, 120)
    {}
};
```

**My problem:**

All animals must reproduce, and they all do so the same way. In this example, I include only `rabbits` and `wolves`, however I include more `Animals`.

**My question:**

How can I modify `ANIMAL::Reproduce()` to find out the type of animal on position `field[x][y]`, and to call `new()` on that particular type? (i.e. `rabbit` would call `new rabbit()`, `wolf` would call `new wolf()`)

```
bool ANIMAL::Reproduce(CELL field[40][30], int x, int y)
{
//field[x][y] holds the animal that must reproduce
//find out what type of animal I am
//reproduce, spawn underneath me
field[x+1][y] = new  /*rabbit/wolf/any animal I decide to make*/;
}
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Define a pure virtual method, clone, in Animal:

```
virtual Animal* clone () const = 0;
```

Then, a particular animal, like Rabbit, would define clone as follows:

```
Rabbit* clone () const {
    return new Rabbit(*this);}
```

Return types are covariant, so `Rabbit*` is okay in Rabbit's definition. It doesn't have to be Animal*.

Do that for all animals.

Then in reproduce, just call `clone()`.